# How can I remove an empty folder that I created manually inside the Photos library?

Tags: photos, macos

I accidentally created an empty folder inside my Photos library.

[image]

My import process is a bit unusual.

I first import photos from my iPhone as usual. Then I locate the newly imported photos in Finder inside the Photos library file and copy them to a SMB share. That's when I accidentally had created a new empty folder inside a folder for one of the imports. That import was then deleted and all the image files disappeared. However, the empty folder is still there and it's basically junk.

I'd like to remove this entire directory tree: 2019/05/22/20190522-10460/New Folder With Items

I tried the repair function but it didn't help.

Deleting this directory tree manually breaks the Photos library.

How can I delete this junk?

Comment: have you tried removing just the "New Folder with Items" folder only?

Comment: Yes, I was able to delete it. However, that broke the Photos library. Luckily, Photos was able to repair it and the stale directory structure was gone. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by first deleting in Finder the "New Folder With Items" folder, then exiting Photos and immediately starting it again in the repair mode. Once repair was finished the stale directory tree was gone. I since then have imported over a thousand photos and videos and everything seems to be O.K. I guess problem is solved :)